# How to count number of groups in a vector?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to count the number of groups in a vector. In this case, the definition of groups is the maximal sequence of the same value in consecutive order. For example:

- `['T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T']`

  has 7 groups.
- `['H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H']`

  has 5 groups
- `['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H']`

  has 7 groups

Any ideas? I was thinking of a for loop to check at each iteration, though I think there's a simpler method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, the mentioned data structure is known as [**`list`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list). You may use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find the groups as:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> my_list = ['T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T']

>>> len(list(groupby(my_list)))
7
```

Comment: I got the following error `len(list(groupby(my_list)))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: @user2105555 You must have defined some variable with the name `list`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `itertools groupby` to achieve your goal

```
from itertools import groupby
a = ['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H']
print (len(list(groupby(a))))
```

Comment: I got the following error  `print (len(list(groupby(a))))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Answer (score 2):

You want to know how many times the element has changed, you can also use a regular for loop to check this:

```
lst = ['T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T']
sum(1 for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i] != lst[i+1]) + 1
# 7
```

---

Or another option as @MoinuddinQuadri commented, use `zip`:

```
sum(1 for x, y in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]) if x != y) + 1
# 7
```

---

Some benchmarks on python 2.7:

```
import random
from itertools import groupby
lst = [random.choice(["T", "H"]) for _ in range(1000000)]

%timeit sum(1 for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i] != lst[i+1]) + 1
10 loops, best of 3: 111 ms per loop

%timeit sum(1 for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if x != y) + 1
10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop

%timeit len(list(groupby(lst)))
10 loops, best of 3: 73.8 ms per loop
```

And, benchmarks on Python 3.4:

```
# using `range`
mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "lst = ['T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T']; sum(1 for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i] != lst[i+1]) + 1"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.33 usec per loop

# using `zip`
mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "lst = ['T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T']; sum(1 for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if a !=b) + 1"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 usec per loop

# using `groupby`
mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "from itertools import groupby"  "lst = ['T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T']; len(list(groupby(lst)))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 usec per loop
```

Comment: even better to use `zip` for `sum`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Yeah, I am trying to avoid the copy but not sure if indexing the list is cheaper than copy.

Comment: Performance wise `zip` will be faster. In python3, `zip` is a generator hence need not to worry about copy

Comment: Looks like in Python2.7, indexed version is slightly faster (with very little difference) because `zip()` creates copy in that

Comment: BTW you may replace `lst[:-1]` with `lst`. `zip` takes care of that :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Yeah, they are mostly comparable. I added some benchmarks here.

Comment: added the results for python3.4 as well. Hope you won't mind editing the answer. Please feel free to revert in case you don't want it to be the part of answer.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri That's interesting. `zip` does make it faster in python3. And I am glad you made the edit. It makes the answer more complete.